# how to change size of svg image in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, svg, flutter-dependencies

I used   `flutter_svg: ^0.18.0` to use svg images inside my project. But I cannot able to find a proper way to change the size of it.

Here's my code

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: Center(
      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/morelights.svg'),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: SVG images are designed to be dynamic in size to whatever view it's set in, what you are looking for is setting the sizes for the child that's hosting the SVG itself

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The key hint is to use `fit` attribute like this:

```
SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/svg/notification.svg',
      height: 5, width: 5,
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown
        )
```

Comment: This was the only solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Missed the `fit: BoxFit.scaleDown`.

Comment: worked only this one!

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution for this :)

**Steps**

1. Wrap svg icon inside a container. ( Container should be a child widget)
2. Set color of the container to transparent.
3. Change the size of the container. (Svg icon inhert the size of parent widget.)

Note: You can use IconButton widget as well. Container works better in my case :)

**Example**

[image: dart code]

[image: output]

Comment: `Center` widget did the trick for me

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution by accident. Wrap **SvgPicture** with **Container** widget and add **alignment**.

That way you can freely **change the width and height** of the SvgPicture.

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  alignment: Alignment.center, // <---- The magic
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/icons/svg-image.svg',
     semanticsLabel: 'Image',
     height: 50,
     width: 50,
  ),
),
```

Hope this works in your case

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap your SvgPicture widget with IconButton

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: (){},
  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
      icDate,
      height: 24,
      width: 24,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I think it is a weird hack to wrap your SvgPicture into an IconButton with an empty onPressed function.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to use properties width and height of svg picture.

```
SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/images/bm-icon1.svg',
         width: 18.0,
         height: 18.0,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
You can use the [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) to easily achieve this:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 150.0,
  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/morelights.svg',),
)
```

**Original Answer:**

You can specify the height and width in the asset constructor itself:

```
SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/morelights.svg', height: 100, width: 150)
```

Read all the available properties in this document: [SvgPicture.asset](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg/latest/svg/SvgPicture/SvgPicture.asset.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a Container widget as the SvgPicture.asset() will always take the full available height or width of the parent. you can size the Container widget height and width to get the desirable sizing you want for your SVG.

```
Container(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/morelights.svg'),
                  height: 100,
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap the **SvgPicture.asset** widget with an **IconButton**, This property have the behavior to overwrite this problem. the sample code is given below.

```
IconButton(
           icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg_images/ic_plane.svg',
              color:  const Color(0xffFF5D2A),
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
            ), onPressed: () {  },
           ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `height` and `width` parameters of [`SvgPicture.asset`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg/latest/svg/SvgPicture/SvgPicture.asset.html):

```
Center(child: SvgPicture.asset(icon, height: 20, width: 20))
```